# Convert BindingList<MyObject> to List<MyObject> c#

Tags: c#, bindinglist

How can I convert BindingList to List ?

Comment: BindingList implements the IList interface. Are you sure you need an actual `List`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
List<int> list = yourBindingList.ToList();
```

int is your type =)

Comment: I don't see a ToList() or Cast() method with my BindingList nor in MSDN. Is this a different BindingList than System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>?

Comment: @RichShealer - A bit late but you need to make sure you add the using System.Linq; ToList() is an extension method.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .NET 2.0, then this is the solution:

```
public List<T> ToList()
{
    return new List<T>(this); // this - is a BindingList compatible object
}
```

Answer (score 2):

List list = yourBindingList.Cast().ToList();